# Is there a Jythonic way to represent an XML file in a Swing tree?

Tags: xml, swing, jython

I have an XML file that I'd like to represent visually in a tree.  If I were to do this, I'd have to use Jython, and we only have version 2.5.0 available on our system.  I have no Java experience (and have a hard time reading it), but a little Swing experience (through Jython) and have heard I might be able to do this with a JTree().  I've seen some Java Swing examples of this, but does anyone know of a Jythonic way to do it?  Please be aware that I only have certain XML parsers available to me - I am currently using the one in xml.etree.ElementTree.

EDIT:
I tried to monkey with Chui Tey's example a little bit and attempted this:

```
from java import awt
from javax import swing
from java.lang import System
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class XmlTreeModel(swing.tree.TreeModel):
    def __init__(self, etree):
        self.etree = etree
    def getRoot(self):
        return self.etree.getroot()
    def getChildCount(self, object):
        return len(object)
    def getChild(self, parent, index):
        return parent[index]

class Viewer(swing.JFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__()
    def display(self, fileName):
        xmlObject = ElementTree.parse(fileName)
        xmlTreeModel = XmlTreeModel(xmlObject)
        jTree = swing.JTree(xmlTreeModel)
        self.contentPane.add(jTree)
        self.contentPane.setPreferredSize( awt.Dimension(100, 200) )        
        self.setTitle("Tree")        
        self.pack()
        self.setDefaultCloseOperation(swing.JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
        self.windowClosing = self.exit
        self.setLocationRelativeTo(None)
        self.setVisible(True)
    def exit(self, event):
        System.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    viewer = Viewer()
    viewer.display('my.xml')
```

Unfortunately, it raises an exception when it gets to `self.contentPane.add(xmlTreeModel)`, saying

> TypeError: add(): 1st arg can't be coerced to java.awt.PopupMenu, java.awt.Component

Am I not able to test it simply by adding it to the content pane?

EDIT: It was missing a JTree.  Updated the code with this fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement [javax.swing.tree.TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) by subclassing.

Below is some untested code. 
Sprinkle liberally with prints to figure out what's going on.

```
from javax.swing.tree import TreeModel

class XmlTreeModel(TreeModel):

  def __init__(self, etree):
    self.etree = etree

  def getRoot(self):
    return self.etree.getroot()

  def getChildCount(self, object):
    return len(object)

  def getChild(self, parent, index)
    return parent[index]

  # ignore for now - not modifying XML
  def addTreeModelListener(self, listener): pass
  def removeTreeModelListener(self, listener): pass
  def valueForPathChanged(self, path, new_value): pass
```

Comment: i gave it a try and added code to my question.  a quick google of the exception just returned a lot of java that i can't read, any chance you recognize it?

Comment: A JTree uses TreeModel to get its data.
self.contentPane.add(JTree(xmlTreeModel))